# How can I insert a framed box inside a table?

Tags: tables, diagrams, framed

I'm trying to accomplish the result in shown in following picture.

[image]

So far I have tried :

```
\begin{tabular}[h]{cm{5cm}m{5cm}c}
  fingerprint & Signature1 & \rule{5cm}{.5pt}  & fingerprint \\
  & & & \\
  \fbox{  \vspace{5cm} \rule{2cm}{0pt} }  & Signature2 & \rule{5cm}{.5pt} &  \fbox{ \vspace{5cm} \rule{2cm}{0pt} } \\
\end{tabular}
```

But the resulting `fbox` are really small, I thought about creating an image of the desired size and including, but I believe LaTeX has the tools needed to accomplish the task without external files.  What I am surely missing is creating a simple framed box of a given size though, and I am not sure about being able to insert in a tabular environment.

Comment: You can't use `\vspace` inside an `\fbox`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The optional argument of `\tabular` or `array` isn't a placement option. The optional argument set the vertical alignment of `tabular`. Working parameters are `b`, `t` and `c`.
2. `fbox` works like a `hbox` and you can use vertical space inside a single `hbox`. You can combine two rules for specifying the width and height.

   ```
   \fbox{\rule{2cm}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{5cm}}
   ```

   You can also set a single `minipage` inside `fbox` with a width and length.

Here is one possibility:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cm{5cm}m{5cm}c}
  fingerprint &  &  & fingerprint \\
  \smash{\fbox{\rule{2cm}{0pt}\rule[-3cm]{0pt}{3cm}}} & Signature 1 & \rule{5cm}{.5pt} &  \smash{\fbox{\rule{2cm}{0pt}\rule[-3cm]{0pt}{3cm}}}  \\[1cm]
  & Signature2 & \rule{5cm}{.5pt} &   \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the real height of the boxes.

Comment: @egreg: What do you mean? The command smash?

Comment: Try setting some text below the tabular. It will overstrike it.

Comment: @egreg: Of course. The height of the `fbox` will be ignored. I know this. Do you think I should add a small explanation of smash?

Answer (score 8):

Or use TikZ directly

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum height=2.9cm,draw,minimum width=2.1cm,label={[inner sep=3mm]90:\textsf{fingerprint 1}}] {};
\node[minimum height=2.9cm,draw,minimum width=2.1cm,label={[inner sep=3mm]90:\textsf{fingerprint 2}}] at (10cm,0) {};
\node (sig1) at (3,0.8) {\textsf{signature 1}};\draw (sig1.east) -- ++(3.7cm,0);
\node (sig2) at (3,-.5) {\textsf{signature 2}};\draw (sig2.east) -- ++(3.7cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ikks: I don't think it can be recommended enough. Every document I write now involves PGF/TikZ. It's worth investing a little time getting to know. [The manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) is a great way to learn it and see the kinds of things it can do. [TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/) also has a lot of self contained examples to browse through and learn from.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\framebox` with its optional width argument and then inside of it a `\rule{0pt}{<height>}` as follows:

```
\framebox[<width>]{\rule{0pt}{<height>}}
```

Note that the amount of `\fboxsep` is added to all sides.

Answer (score 3):

Marco already points out some weak points in your code. To get vertical centering, the easiest thing is to use tabulars inside a tabular:

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
% First column
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  Fingerprint 1 \\
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \framebox[2cm]{\rule{0pt}{5cm}}
\end{tabular}
&
% second column
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
Signature 1 & \rule{5cm}{.4pt} \\[3ex]
Signature 2 & \rule{5cm}{.4pt} 
\end{tabular}
&
% third column
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  Fingerprint 2 \\
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \framebox[2cm]{\rule{0pt}{5cm}}
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

With `\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}` you ensure that the box is *exactly* as wide and as high as you prescribe (in this case 2cm wide and 5cm high).